I want to add buttons on QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget
qt can add buttons to widgets in Windows, but QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget can't. I want to add a fixed button to the QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget. How do I do that
I tried it by way of layout
QPushButton *button1 = new QPushButton("button1")；
QPushButton *button2 = new QPushButton("button2");
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
layout->addWidget(button1);
layout->addWidget(button2);
QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget* m_vtkOpenGLWidget = new QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget(this);
Widget->setLayout(layout);

